# Cannot connect angular front to node backend

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io

I'm currently developing game app. I have started with authorization via FB and now i got stuck on connecting front-end angular with back-end node.
My folder contains 2 subfolders without any connections or dependencies between them: **client** and **server**.

**Client** contains scaffolded yeoman application based on angular generator so that my front end is fired with *grunt serve*. I'm using here angular-socket-io by btford.

**Server** contains nothing but basic server allowing to connect and loggs to console when someone will connect via socket.io.

My problem lies on client folder, front-end part, where:

```
angular.module('battleshipsApp')
    .factory('socket', function (socketFactory) {
        var myIoSocket = io.connect('http://localhost:5432');
        var mySocket = socketFactory({
            ioSocket: myIoSocket
        });
       return mySocket;
    });
```

doesn't work.

I think i linked  everything i needed:

```
src="bower_components/angular-socket-io/socket.js"
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
src="bower_components/angular-socket-io/mock/socket-io.js"
```

Here my simple server:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    var logIn = new Date();
    console.log(logIn + ' user connected')

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    var logOut = new Date();
        console.log(logOut + ' bye bye')
    })
});

http.listen(5432, function(){
  console.log('listening on localhost:5432');
});
```

And I can't figure out why these two cannot connect.
I couldn't find any answers which could fit my problem in google.
I'm looking right now on both terminals, one with *grunt serve* in action and one with *nodemon server.js* and no errors, no connections.
Also there are no errors on dev tools console in chrome on front-end side.

Any help? Or maybe approach for this app with my structure is bad?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to add to your server :

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```